# How to write a cronjob in amazon linux

Tags: linux, cron

I have an `EC2` instance and I have the following `bash` script which I need to run;

1. Every 1 minute
2. The same script every 12 hours

```
TOKEN=$(aws ecr get-login-password --region us-east-2)
# echo $TOKEN

CONVERT_ME="AWS:${TOKEN}"

BASE_64_ENCODED=$(echo -n "${CONVERT_ME}" | base64)

echo $BASE_64_ENCODED

jq -n --arg TOKEN $TOKEN '{"HttpHeaders": {"User-Agent": "Docker-Client/19.03.13-ce (linux)"},"auths": {"337198119645.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com": {"auth": $TOKEN}}}' > ~/.docker/config.json
```

If I do something like below, it says `command not found`

```
* * * * * update.sh
```

So I tried `crontab -e` and put the above command, how can I make sure if it is executing? is there a timer we can track? or am I doing this all wrong?

Thank you

Comment: Using [AWS SSM Automation](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mt/automate-running-tasks-using-amazon-ec2-systems-manager-maintenance-windows/) can be option.

Comment: Where is update.sh stored? Perhaps what you should do is provide the full path to it and see if that helps.